# React native server stops transforming every time

Tags: react-native

React native was working perfectly till today. But, Suddenly I'm facing a weird error. Whenever I try to load js from the react native android app. I'm getting the following messages.. Transforming progress bar is stopping exactly in 96% every time.

[image: Error]

Let me know, If you need any extra information.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you figured it out what was causing it?
I'm having the same issue.

Comment: That was due to a package. In my case, It was MaterialReactNative package. After removing it, Everything is working fine.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, This was due to a package called `MaterialReactNative`. If there is some problem in the package, this will be stopped in transforming. If you want to know which package is making this problem. You can start react native in verbose mode.

```
 react-native start -vvv
```

I hope that this will help few people who are facing the same issue.